# How do I implement object picking, using OBB in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, 3d, raycasting, glut, picking

I am trying to make 3D drawing software. I wanted to have the drag feature so I am using object picking using the OBB algorithm. I am facing problems in understanding the algorithm, and my implementation thus is having bugs.

How do I implement object picking, using OBB in OpenGL? As I am new to OpenGL (free-glut library), a step by step explanation would be helpful.

Comment: Given that this question self admits no relation to video game development (3D drawing software is an entirely differant ballpark), this question would probably be better directed towards the [Computer Graphics Stack Exchange](http://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2):

First you have to implement AABB picking with AABB-ray intersection test. Picking an OBB is then achieved by transforming the ray inside the OBB's local space and doing an intersection test with an unit AABB - local ray. Transforming the ray into the OBB local space is done by transforming the ray origin and ray direction by the inverse of the OBB's transformation matrix.

To get a picking ray, you have to unproject your pick position (mouse position) to the camera near and far planes by transforming it by the inverse view projection matrix. Something like this:

```
vector3 near = vector3(mouse.xy,0,1) * matInverseVP;
vector3 far = vector3(mouse.xy,1,1) * matInverseVP;
vector3 rayOrigin = near;
vector3 rayDirection = normalize(far - near);
```